# Mixed container (fluid + non fluid columns) using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any **clean** possibility to create a **"mixed container"** (fluid + non fluid columns) using Bootstap?

I made an image showing the regular Boostrap containers (regular/fixe and fluid) and at the bottom the one I am looking for (mixed container).

[image: Bootstrap Mixed Container?]

Any idea?

Comment: check this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/brantolsen/Lhj3x3xk/embedded/result/
do you want something like this?

Comment: That's good, thanks! Please create a real response to allow me to validate  your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check this markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="col-xs-6 leftDiv">
        right content fixed width
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="pull-left col-xs-6 rigthDiv">
            left content flexible width
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/brantolsen/Lhj3x3xk/embedded/result/